# How to add query Limit in subs query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, limit

```
SELECT kodeagent
 , IFNULL((
   SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM bsn_data
   WHERE bsn_data.periode LIKE '2018-12-%%'
   AND bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
   AND bsn_data.kodeagent IN(
       SELECT bsn_data.kodeagent
       FROM bsn_data
       WHERE bsn_data.periode LIKE '2018-12-%%'
       AND bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
       GROUP BY bsn_data.kodeagent ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC LIMIT 1
       )
   ), 0) AS totps
FROM bsn_kode_agent
WHERE fungsi = 'sales agent'
ORDER BY totps DESC
```

Getting the result

This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

How do I solve that? I want add limit query in subquery.. thank you..

Comment: tag it with mariadb then

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: does it work with the "=" operator?  I mean 
....
bsn_data.kodeagent = (
       SELECT bsn_data.kodeagent
...

Comment: is it `MariaDB` or `mySql`? Please correct it.

Comment: Some **sample data** and the **expected result** would help solve your question quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have anything to check my answer. Please try this, have wrapped the subquery in anther to provide a tmp table alias(tmp_bsn_data):

```
SELECT kodeagent
 , IFNULL((
   SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM bsn_data
   WHERE bsn_data.periode LIKE '2018-12-%%'
   AND bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
   AND bsn_data.kodeagent IN( select tmp_bsn_data.kodeagent from (
       SELECT bsn_data.kodeagent
       FROM bsn_data
       WHERE bsn_data.periode LIKE '2018-12-%%'
       AND bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
       GROUP BY bsn_data.kodeagent ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC LIMIT 1
       ) tmp_bsn_data
       )
   ), 0) AS totps
FROM bsn_kode_agent
WHERE fungsi = 'sales agent'
ORDER BY totps DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT ka.kodeagent
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM bsn_data d
        WHERE d.periode >= '2018-12-01' AND
              d.periode < '2019-01-01' AND
              d.kodeupline2 = ka.kodeagent AND
              d.kodeagent = (SELECT d2.kodeagent
                             FROM bsn_data d2
                                  d2.periode >= '2018-12-01' AND
                                  d2.periode < '2019-01-01' AND
                                  d2.kodeupline2 = ka.kodeagent
                             GROUP BY d2.kodeagent
                             ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
                             LIMIT 1
                            )
        ) AS totps
FROM bsn_kode_agent ka
WHERE ka.fungsi = 'sales agent'
ORDER BY totps DESC;
```

Notes:

- Don't use string operations on dates!  Use proper date operations.
- Use table aliases and qualify the table names.
- `=` can use `limit`, although `in` cannot.
- `COUNT()` doesn't return `NULL`, so there is no need for a `NULL` comparison.

I still don't think the query will work, because you have a doubly nested correlation clause.  But this does fix your immediate problem.

If this still doesn't work, ask *another* question, provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`

In this case, it should be easy to turn it into a `JOIN`.

Change the middle query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
    FROM  bsn_data
    WHERE  bsn_data.periode LIKE '2018-12-%%'
      AND  bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
      AND  bsn_data.kodeagent IN (
        SELECT  bsn_data.kodeagent
            FROM  bsn_data
            WHERE  bsn_data.periode LIKE '2018-12-%%'
              AND  bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
            GROUP BY  bsn_data.kodeagent
            ORDER BY  COUNT(1) DESC
            LIMIT  1 
                          )
```

to

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  bsn_data.kodeagent
            FROM  bsn_data
            WHERE  bsn_data.periode >= '2018-12-01'
              AND  bsn_data.periode  < '2018-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
              AND  bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
            GROUP BY  bsn_data.kodeagent
            ORDER BY  COUNT(1) DESC
            LIMIT  1 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  bsn_data  ON x.kodeagent = bsn_data.kodeagent
    WHERE  bsn_data.periode >= '2018-12-01'
      AND  bsn_data.periode  < '2018-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND  bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
```

Indexes:

```
bsn_data:  INDEX(kodeupline2, periode, kodeagent)  -- in this order
bsn_data:  (kodeagent)  -- is this the PRIMARY KEY?
```

But wait!  Can't that be simplified to

```
SELECT  COUNT(1) AS ct
    FROM  bsn_data
    WHERE  bsn_data.periode >= '2018-12-01'
      AND  bsn_data.periode <  '2018-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND  bsn_data.kodeupline2 = bsn_kode_agent.kodeagent
    GROUP BY  bsn_data.kodeagent
    ORDER BY  COUNT(1) DESC
    LIMIT  1
```

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB offers "window functions" which can be exploited for for this I believe (also referring to previous question which seems to require just the count from the "top 3" agents):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bsn_kode_agent(
>    kodeagent VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   ,fungsi    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO bsn_kode_agent(kodeagent,fungsi) 
>   VALUES
>   ('a','sales agent')
> , ('b','sales agent');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bsn_data(
>    kodeagent   VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
>   ,kodeupline2 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
>   ,periode     DATE  NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO bsn_data(kodeagent,kodeupline2,periode) 
> VALUES 
>   ('a','b1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','b1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','b1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','c1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','c1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','c1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','d1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','d1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','e1','2018-12-01')
> , ('a','f1','2018-12-01')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     b.kodeagent
>   , IFNULL( SUM( d.total ), 0 )  AS totps
> FROM bsn_kode_agent AS b
> LEFT JOIN (
>         SELECT
>             tableb.kodeupline2
>           , tableb.kodeagent
>           , tableb.total
>           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tableb.kodeagent
>                                  ORDER BY tableb.total DESC) as rn
>         FROM (
>             SELECT
>                 bsn_data.kodeupline2
>               , bsn_data.kodeagent
>               , COUNT( 1 ) total
>             FROM bsn_data
>             WHERE  bsn_data.periode >= '2018-12-01'
>               AND  bsn_data.periode <  '2018-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
>             GROUP BY
>                 bsn_data.kodeupline2
>               , bsn_data.kodeagent
>         ) AS tableb
>     ) d ON d.kodeagent = b.kodeagent and d.rn <=3 
> WHERE b.fungsi = 'sales agent'
> group by
>     b.kodeagent
> ORDER BY
>     totps DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> kodeagent | totps
> :-------- | ----:
> a         |     8
> b         |     0
> ```

Below: The subquery result if run standalone. Note  it is the `rn` column allows subsequent filtering of just the agents with the highest counts.

> ```
>          SELECT
>             tableb.kodeupline2
>           , tableb.kodeagent
>           , tableb.total
>           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tableb.kodeagent
>                                  ORDER BY tableb.total DESC) as rn
>         FROM (
>             SELECT
>                 bsn_data.kodeupline2
>               , bsn_data.kodeagent
>               , COUNT( 1 ) total
>             FROM bsn_data
>             WHERE  bsn_data.periode >= '2018-12-01'
>               AND  bsn_data.periode <  '2018-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
>             GROUP BY
>                 bsn_data.kodeupline2
>               , bsn_data.kodeagent
>         ) AS tableb
> ```
>
> ```
> kodeupline2 | kodeagent | total | rn
> :---------- | :-------- | ----: | -:
> b1          | a         |     3 |  1
> c1          | a         |     3 |  2
> d1          | a         |     2 |  3
> e1          | a         |     1 |  4
> f1          | a         |     1 |  5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=976549969ca060beab8c64d9103e41c0)*

Please also note how useful it is to have some sample data, **BUT** as this was not provided I may have made incorrect assumptions about the sample seen here - it is ALWAYS better if sample data is supplied with the question.